# Set Parameter On click C3Js from columns/data name

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to pass the value of **data columns** into the **event onclick** on c3Js ?

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
      ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
    ],
    onclick: function() {
      alert('a');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

---

### Case

Can i change the `alert('a')` to `alert(columns[0][0]) // or what,sorry i have no idea`, which output will be **data1** if i clicked the blue line, and so are if i clicked the yellow ones it will be alerting **data2**.

---

### Purpose

What i'am trying to do is.. i want to make new link by click the graph and sent the primary key from the data parameters.. The Problem is i don't know how to pass the columns name from the selected line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-onclick),
data.onclick will

> receive d and element as the arguments. d is the data clicked and element is the element clicked

So try changing your code to:

`onclick: function(d, element) {
      alert(d);
    }`

(Or better yet, use console.log if it's just for debugging)

If you run into any further problems, let me know and I will update my answer.